# Problems with keyboard layout change. Local issue or bug?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, bug-reporting

In the past week and a half there have been many Ubuntu Base upgrades, and i did not restart each time after an upgrade. Now that i have restarted the changing between languages via the shortcut (Alt+L Shift) no longer works (i am forced to change it in the panel with the mouse… very uncomfortable).

I have already attempted to change the shortcut to a different combination, and then changed it back. It still does not work. Restarting several times (as if it were Windows) doesn't work either.

Everything worked perfectly before.

The question is:

1. Is there anybody else who experiences this problem or is this a local issue that can be resolved with the configuration change?
2. If it is a bug, what package it is a bug with (so that i can report it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a known bug, with the following [work around](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322/comments/338):

"To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the new packages improve the situation for you, you can use apt-mark to hold these packages at these versions.

If the new packages cause a regression for you, use 'sudo ppa-purge ppa:attente/modifier-only-input-switch' to restore the versions currently in archive."